# Delegate from class A to B to C to D

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app that contains questions with multiple choice. I thought I understand how to use delegate but I think something missing in my code or I'm not in the right direction.

I have class Answer with deleagate:

```
    public protocol AnswerDelegate: AnyObject {
        func answerSelected(answer: Answer, isSelected: bool)
    }
    public class Answer: UIView {
       struct Data {
          let isSelected: Bool
          let text: String?
          init(isSelected: Bool = false, text: String? = nil) {
          self.isSelected = isSelected
          self.text = text
        }
}
// a weak reference to AnswerDelegate
public weak var delegate: AnswerDelegate?

// a function that handles selected answer
@objc func handleSelect() {
    delegate?.answerSelected(answer: self, isSelected: isSelected)
 }
```

then I have a B class to group the Answer class and create a new delegate that subclass the AnswerDelegate:

```
    public protocol MultipleChoiceDelegate: AnswerDelegate {}
    
    public class MultipleChoice: UIView, AnswerDelegegate {
          struct MultipleChoiceData {
             var answers: [Answer]?
             let message: String?
          init(answers: [Answer] = [], message: String? = nil) {
              self.answers = answers
              self.message = message
          }
    // a weak reference to MultipleChoiceDelegate
    public weak var delegate: MultipleChoiceDelegate?
    var answers: [Answer] = []
   }
```

then a C class:

```
    public protocol QuestionDelegate: AnswerDelegate {}
    public class Question: UIView, AnswerDelegate {
        struct QuestionData {
           let questionString: String?
           var answers: [Answer]
        init(questionString: String? = nil, answers: [Answer] = [])   {
        self.questionString = questionString
        self.answers = answers
        }
}
    // a weak reference to QuestionDelegate
    public weak var delegate: QuestionDelegate?
}
```

In my viewController I want to check selected answers

```
    class QuestionsViewController: QuestionDelegate {
       let question = Question()
       override func viewDidLoad() {
          question.delegate = self
      }
    
    func answerSelected(answer: Answer, isSelected: Bool) {
      print("selected") // when answer selected, it is not print
    }
}
```

Is the way I use delegate wrong or something missing? Any help and guidance are appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: Your code is missing lots of closing braces. A bit hard to understand.

Comment: You do not set `MultipleChoice.delegate` or `Answer.delegate` anywhere, so they're nil when you call them. I don't really understand what you're trying to do but you need to set the delegate of the child class in its parent, for each class. Then pass any information or method calls through that chain of delegation.

Comment: Thank you and my apologies for not being clear in my post. I want to know which answer isSelected if I choose answers from my view (viewController). But I guess I'm not doing the right thing, that's why I couldn't get "print("selected")" when set the breakpoint in QuestionViewController. @SwiftCODA, you mentioned that I didn't set MultipleChoice.delegate or Answer.delegate anywhere. Does that mean I need to set these two delegates in my viewController or in Question class? Am I missing some functions that sets isSelected in Question class or MultipleChoice class?

Comment: @Kuru wherever you set a property to be an instance of a class, eg `var multipleChoice = MultipleChoice()` you set `multipleChoice.delegate = self` in that same file. I keep going over you code and I just don't understand what's going on. Do you have screenshots of your app running? I feel like you might be overcomplicating the code. From what I can tell, the only mention of the `Answer` class is when you specify the array type. You never populate your arrays with instances of `Answer`